# how to get this code working with loadStrings();?

Tags: string, text, load, processing

I would like to get this code working with loadStrings();

Now the code loads the text through *String string =*, I would like to change that, in order to make it read a .txt file.

I've tried various ways, but I always seem to get an error code. Is it possible?

```
PFont font;
String string = "Processing is an open source programming language and environment for people who want to program images, animation, and interactions.";
int fontSize = 10;
int specificWidth = 150;
int lineSpacing = 2;

int textHeight;

void setup() {
  size(600,600);
  background(0);

  font = createFont("Times New Roman", fontSize);
  textFont(font,fontSize);
  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  fill(60);
  stroke(60);
  rect(100,100,specificWidth, calculateTextHeight(string, specificWidth, fontSize, lineSpacing));
  fill(255);
  text(string, 100,100,specificWidth,1000);
}

int calculateTextHeight(String string, int specificWidth, int fontSize, int lineSpacing) {
  String[] wordsArray;
  String tempString = "";
  int numLines = 0;
  float textHeight;

  wordsArray = split(string, " ");

  for (int i=0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
    if (textWidth(tempString + wordsArray[i]) < specificWidth) {
 tempString += wordsArray[i] + " ";
    }
    else {
 tempString = wordsArray[i] + " ";
 numLines++;
    }
  }

  numLines++; //adds the last line

  textHeight = numLines * (textDescent() + textAscent() + lineSpacing);
  return(round(textHeight));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to sketch -> Add File to add the text file then use this code to get the string from the text file:

```
PFont font;
String string = "";
int fontSize = 10;
int specificWidth = 150;
int lineSpacing = 2;
String lines[];

int textHeight;

void setup() {
  size(600,600);

  lines[] = loadStrings("text.txt");

  font = createFont("Times New Roman", fontSize);
  textFont(font,fontSize);
  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  string = lines[0];
  fill(60);
  stroke(60);
  rect(100,100,specificWidth, calculateTextHeight(string, specificWidth, fontSize, lineSpacing));
  fill(255);
  text(string, 100,100,specificWidth,1000);
}

int calculateTextHeight(String string, int specificWidth, int fontSize, int lineSpacing) {
  String[] wordsArray;
  String tempString = "";
  int numLines = 0;
  float textHeight;

  wordsArray = split(string, " ");

  for (int i=0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
    if (textWidth(tempString + wordsArray[i]) < specificWidth) {
 tempString += wordsArray[i] + " ";
    }
    else {
 tempString = wordsArray[i] + " ";
 numLines++;
    }
  }

  numLines++; //adds the last line

  textHeight = numLines * (textDescent() + textAscent() + lineSpacing);
  return(round(textHeight));
}
```

Note that in this example the entire string is on the first line of the text file. If you want to get strings from other lines then you need to access different parts of the "lines" array.

Comment: @Scarnix a quick note to say that you shouldn't a) declare the String Array nor b) load the file in the draw() loop. Proper implementation would be to declare it globally, load it in setup(), then iterate through it in draw() ...